# Symfony (OrangeHRM): Error for Dot in php name function

Tags: php, symfony, orangehrm

I used symfony (OrangeHRM) with no error till yesterday but today I have this error:

```
[09-Jun-2014 08:53:29] PHP Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '.', expecting '(' in C:\xampp\htdocs\hrb\symfony\lib\vendor\symfony\lib\plugins\sfDoctrinePlugin\lib\vendor\doctrine\Doctrine\Record.php on line 2023
```

The line code is this:

```
public function synString.fromCharCodeonizeWithArray(array $array, $deep = true)
```

In php is an error to insert Dot in name function.

I didn't make any change, what happened? I know that is an error on php, but I used the file that contain it for months without any error.

In Record.php there are many lines with this problem.

Comment: This is difficult to say without having access to your system. It looks like someone did a bad Find All & Replace. Are you using any VCS (git, svn, etc)? If so you could see who and when changed that file.

Comment: I can't play detective with your computer to figure out what happened, but try `composer update --prefer-source` to fix the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two functions in `Record.php` have the same signature:

```
public function fromArray(array $array, $deep = true)
```

or

```
public function synchronizeWithArray(array $array, $deep = true)
```

Indeed, it's look like a fail on a mass search/replace. So revert the modifications. But as it is a plugin, it should be set as an external and shouldn't be committed.

Comment: You are right something must have happened, I wonder how I have done it but it must be this way, I restored a backup and the file was correct. 
thanks